# How to remove punctuation and irrelevant words with stopwords (Text Mining)

Tags: python, text, nltk, stop-words, mining

The libraries I'm using are:

```
      import pandas as pd
      import string
      from nltk.corpus import stopwords
      import nltk
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
     df = pd.DataFrame({'Send': ['Golgi body, membrane-bound organelle of eukaryotic cells (cells 
                                  with clearly defined nuclei).',
                                 'The Golgi apparatus is responsible for transporting, modifying, and 
                                  packaging proteins',
                                 'Non-foliated metamorphic rocks do not have a platy or sheet-like 
                                  structure.',
                                 'The process of metamorphism does not melt the rocks.'], 
                                 'Class': ['biology', 'biology', 'geography', 'geography']})

     print(df)

                              Send                           Class
         Golgi body, membrane-bound organelle of eukary...  biology
         The Golgi apparatus is responsible for transpo...  biology
         Non-foliated metamorphic rocks do not have a p...  geography
         The process of metamorphism does not melt the ...  geography
```

I would like to generate a function for cleaning the data in the 'Send' column. I would like to:

1. Remove the score;
2. Remove stop words 'stopwords';
3. Return a new data frame with the 'Send' column containing the "clean words".

The attempt was to develop the following function:

```
      def Text_Process(mess): 
           nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]
           nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)  
           return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

However, the return is not feeling exactly what I would like. When I run:

```
        Text_Process(df['Send'])
```

The output is:

```
       ['Golgi', 'body,', 'membrane-bound', 'organelle', 'eukaryotic', 'cells', '(cells', 'clearly',
        'defined', 'nuclei).The', 'Golgi', 'apparatus', 'responsible',  'transporting,', 
        'modifying,', 'packaging', 'proteinsNon-foliated', 'metamorphic', 'rocks',
        'platy', 'sheet-like', 'structure.The', 'process', 'metamorphism',
        'melt', 'rocks.']
```

I would like the output to be the dataframe with the modified 'Send' column:

```
       df = pd.DataFrame({'Send': ['Golgi membrane bound organelle eukaryotic cells cells 
                                   clearly defined nuclei',
                                  'Golgi apparatus responsible transporting modifying                                     
                                   packaging proteins',
                                 'Non foliated metamorphic rocks platy sheet like 
                                  structure',
                                 'process metamorphism mel rocks'], 
                                 'Class': ['biology', 'biology', 'geography', 'geography']})
```

I would like the output to be the dataframe with the column 'Send' clean (without score and without words that are not relevant).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script to clean the column. Note you may want to add more words to the stopword set to meet your requirements.

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Send': ['Golgi body, membrane-bound organelle of eukaryotic cells (cells with clearly defined nuclei).',
              'The Golgi apparatus is responsible for transporting, modifying, and packaging proteins',
              'Non-foliated metamorphic rocks do not have a platy or sheet-like structure.',
              'The process of metamorphism does not melt the rocks.'],
     'Class': ['biology', 'biology', 'geography', 'geography']})

table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

def text_process(mess):
    words = re.split(r'\W+', mess)
    nopunc = [w.translate(table) for w in words]
    nostop =  ' '.join([word for word in nopunc if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')])
    return nostop

df['Send'] = df.apply(lambda row: text_process(row.Send), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                                                 Send      Class
0  Golgi body membrane bound organelle eukaryotic cells cells clearly defined nuclei     biology
1               Golgi apparatus responsible transporting modifying packaging proteins    biology
2                          Non foliated metamorphic rocks platy sheet like structure   geography
3                                                    process metamorphism melt rocks   geography
```